# Como manter um registro no banco de dados, porem, oculto para o sistema?

Tags: postgresql

Tenho um aplicação em Delphi e preciso que nessa aplicação quando o usuário deletar um registro, esse registro continue no database, mas fique oculto no sistema.

Answer (score 7):

Você poderá aplicar o que é conhecido como exclusão lógica:
No procedimento de exclusão da aplicação executar o comando `UPDATE` ao invés do `DELETE`, alterando o valor da coluna "excluido" para `true`.
Na listagem de registros, considerar somente os que possuem o valor da coluna 'excluído' com os valores `NULL` e `false`.

Comment: Conhecido também como Soft-delete.